# zsh autocorrect, edit option. Possible to bring cursor to the wrong command?

Tags: zsh, autocorrect

This is only a tiny, tiny gripe I just experienced right now.

zsh will try to autocorrect `car someTextFile.txt`. Unfortunately zsh suggests `xar someTextFile.txt` when I really want `cat`.

When I choose the edit option (`e`at the `[nyae]` prompt), zsh presents me with this:
`car someTextFile.txt|` (the `|`is the cursor position). What I would really like is for zsh to place the cursor at the misspelled command. Like this: `car| someTextFile.txt` – is that possible?

Just a small annoyance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to accomplish what you desire. However, for commands that you commonly mistype you can add an alias to your .zshrc:

`alias car='cat'`

That way, when you mistype, 'car' will be run 'cat'.